# Há como remover o time out? PHP

Tags: php, cron, timeout

Estou utilizando uma cron pra rodar um script que lê um arquivo txt de 18 mil linhas e vai inserindo no banco, mas está executando no máximo mil linhas, do nada para, não caiu em nenhum dos erros que poderia ser. Há uma outra forma de fazer?

Comment: Não consegue fazer um insert direto pelo banco com um csv ou algo parecido?

Comment: Ficaria muito cansativo, por isso quero automatizar, estou pegando direto de um ftp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inclua essa linha no inicio do seu arquivo php, ou no php.ini

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```